# Image upload in a node gives required error

Tags: nodes, media

we have a node to which we upload many pictures. This time, after ~ 337 pictures all of the following pictures are marked as failure with an error but as message is just given "**Field Bilder is required**". Bilder (translates to images) is the field we already uploaded 300+ images.

[image: Image upload filed]
[image: "Error" message above]

In the recent Drupal log is no message concerning upload errors. Any clues what could cause this problem?

Comment: What does your log say?
Have you tried a new node with less images? And what is the combined size of the images?

Comment: 1) Which log du you mean? Drupal log (admin/reports/dblog) states nothing.
2) Yes, a new node with less images workes. The node with the error also works but just with the 337 pictures (about 34 not being uploaded)
3) Don't have the exact answer yet as I'm not the person uploading but estimating 100 MB given file size and number of pictures

Comment: All pictures (uploaded and to be uploaded) are 94.7 MB

Comment: Is it possible that you have run out of disk space? Did your hosting provider change anything? Have you check permissions on your upload directory?

Comment: As creating a new node with 200 pictures is possible I'm pretty sure that's not the problem.

Disk Space should be about xxx GB left and as in this directory can still be uploaded new pictures shouldn't be the permissions

Comment: So, you CAN upload images to other fields/node types but not to this one?

Comment: It's just this one specific node. I created a new node of the same type and uploaded 150 new pictures without a problem.

Comment: Could it be that you hit some PHP or apache limit related to number of values you send via your form? Try altering max_input_vars and post_max_size in your php.ini

Comment: I asked our server administrator to increase the values. 

Not sure how Drupal works but when I have a node with x files and add 1 file. Should the post/upload-settings in the ini just trigger for that one file? Will be tested nevertheless thanks!

Comment: we changed for testing: **memory_limit** 512M, **post_max_size** 256M, **upload_max_filesize** 128M, **max_file_uploads** 600 -> same results sadly :/

Comment: What about mysql. Maybe your query is too big?

Comment: Do you know which setting that would be?

Comment: Maybe max_allowed_packet : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062496/how-to-change-max-allowed-packet-size

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the upload is limited due to **php settings**. There is not only a setting for max upload per file, but also a max for a post.

On this page you can find how to solve in this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/422474)

If this doesn't work, there might be a setting for `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`, which cuts off the upload script if it takes too long.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. But that should only be a problem when we upload the files in one upload action. Currently we can't add even one picture to this specific node.

Comment: Do you use anything like IMCE-module or do you have set a limit per album or per user in your drupal system?

Comment: For uploading we use the _Multiupload Imagefield Widget_ module. About which drupal settings are you talking? At least I tried it with an administrator account. But I will take a look if you could tell me which settings you were talking about. Thanks!

Comment: For various extensions of wysiwyg editors, or other drupal modules, you are able to set a limit of number of filers or size of the file folder.

Does every node create a seperate folder for its files? Or are all files dumped into the default > files folder?

Comment: Files are uploaded to __default/files/gallery/<year>/<month>/__ . If that folder would be _full_ uploading a new gallery in october wouldn't be working. But it just works fine :/